# Sql server ODBC driver

Tags: php, sql-server, centos, odbc

I have installed ODBC driver 13 for sql server in centOS 6.9 (Final). it shows in phpinfo.but when I run the script it still shows "could not find driver". here I'm attaching the phpinfo() output. 
[image]

Comment: Where are you running the script from? CLI?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Nope. running the script from browser.

Comment: I believe that's for the mssql_* functions. On my server I have the module "DB-LIB (MS SQL, Sybase)" installed.

Comment: enable php_pdo_odbc.dll in ini file..

Comment: @Scriptman I connect the database through pdo_odbc driver.

Comment: @RaviShrimali I believe .dll for windows. here I'm talking about linux.

Comment: @hmamun Then you need to check if PDO is enabled and you have installed ODBC for PDO. You also need PDO_DBLIB. Have you read http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php ?